# Convert character sequence in row to separate rows in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe, dplyr, datatable

**PROBLEM**

Trying to convert a chracter column which has the following sequence into seperate rows in the order presented in the sequence.

**SAMPLE DATA**

Important to note that both columns are characters

```
df<- data.frame(name=c("Mike","John","Ashook","Rawabee"), 
                sequence = c("[4000.0, 1050.0, 400.0]",
                             "[8000.0, 50.2, 1050.0, 1050.0, 400.0]",
                             "[1000.0, 300.2]",
                             "[400.0]"))

#Both columns are characters
df
     name                              sequence
1    Mike               [4000.0, 1050.0, 400.0]
2    John [8000.0, 50.2, 1050.0, 1050.0, 400.0]
3  Ashook                       [1000.0, 300.2]
4 Rawabee                               [400.0]
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
df
      name  Value
1     Mike 4000.0
2     Mike 1050.0
3     Mike  400.0
4     John 8000.0
5     John   50.2
6     John 1050.0
7     John 1050.0
8     John  400.0
9   Ashook 1000.0
10  Ashook  300.2
11 Rawabee  400.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)


df %>% mutate(sequence = str_remove_all(sequence , '\\[|\\]')) %>% separate_rows(sequence)
# A tibble: 11 x 2
   name    sequence
   <chr>   <chr>   
 1 Mike    4000.0  
 2 Mike    1050.0  
 3 Mike    400.0   
 4 John    8000.0  
 5 John    50.2    
 6 John    1050.0  
 7 John    1050.0  
 8 John    400.0   
 9 Ashook  1000.0  
10 Ashook  300.2   
11 Rawabee 400.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can treat `sequence` column as JSON objects.

```
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(sequence = fromJSON(sequence)) %>%
  ungroup

#   name    sequence
#   <chr>      <dbl>
# 1 Ashook    1000  
# 2 Ashook     300. 
# 3 John      8000  
# 4 John        50.2
# 5 John      1050  
# 6 John      1050  
# 7 John       400  
# 8 Mike      4000  
# 9 Mike      1050  
#10 Mike       400  
#11 Rawabee    400
```

Answer (score 0):

step by step using datatable:

```
library(data.table)

# convert to datatable
df = data.table(df)

# remove brackets
df[, sequence := gsub("\\[|\\]", "", sequence)]

# parse list into columns and drop sequence column
df = cbind(df[, 'name'], df[, tstrsplit(sequence, ", ", fixed=TRUE)])

# melt into long format
df = melt(df, id.vars = "name", value.name = 'Value', na.rm  = TRUE)
```

which results in:

```
> df
   name  Value
  1:    Mike 4000.0
  2:    John 8000.0
  3:  Ashook 1000.0
  4: Rawabee  400.0
  5:    Mike 1050.0
  6:    John   50.2
  7:  Ashook  300.2
  8:    Mike  400.0
  9:    John 1050.0
 10:    John 1050.0
 11:    John  400.0
```